# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property - Though property exists

Tags: javascript

```
var sorted = DocumentListData.Documents.sort(function (a, b) {
    var nameA = a.Document.toLowerCase(),
        nameB = b.Document.toLowerCase();

    return nameA.localeCompare(nameB);
});

for (var i = 0, len = sorted.length; i < len; i++) {

    if (sorted[i].Document=== 'abc') {
        sorted.splice(i, 1);
    }

    if (sorted[i].Document=== 'xyz') {
        sorted.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

I am just breaking my head for one hour on what is the mistake going here. It throws me Document is undefined, though the Document property exists.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Document' of undefined`. When i remove the `sorted.splice(i,1)`, it works and there is no error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're modifying an array that you're iterating over.  `splice(i,1)` removes the ith element.  When you splice the sorted array you're removing elements, so you eventually go past the length of the array, since the loop goes to the original length of the array.  `sorted[i]` is then undefined, and you get the error you're describing.

Generally its never a good idea to modify an array that you're currently iterating over in that fashion.  If you have to do it that way make sure to include if checks to see that `i` is not `>=` to the current length of the array.  But using a while loop is probably a better fit here.

```
var counter =0;
while(counter < sorted.length) {
var doc = sorted[counter].Document;
  if (doc === 'abc' ||doc === 'xyz') {
    sorted.splice(counter, 1);
  }
  else{
   counter++;
  }
}
```

#### A few more thoughts

1. `document` is a predefined variable in the browser environment for javascript, and generally JS has a convention that capitalized variables are only for constructor functions.  So `Document` is probably not a great property name choice.
2. If you don't need to support older versions of IE you can also look into [Array.Prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as a cleaner way of doing what you want

Comment: It fails... as i need to remove both the documents... the array contains both.

Comment: Oh sorry, counter shouldn't iterate when you delete.  I fixed that by adding the else statement in the code block above.  Should work as expected now.

Comment: Thanks ben... is there a solution also where we can do it in traditional if and else way...

Comment: This is using if...else.  What do you mean by traditional if else way?

Comment: The || is just an or.  So this says, go through till you've reached the end of the array, and if the element is abc or xyz then remove it.  Otherwise move on to the next element.

Comment: if (sorted[i].Document=== 'abc') {
    sorted.splice(i, 1);
} else if (sorted[i].Document=== 'xyz') {
    sorted.splice(i, 1);
}

Comment: something like this wont work for us in this situation... just wanted to learn and know

Comment: Sure if you follow that with an else{ counter++} or else{i++} then you can replace the stuff in the while statement with that and it should work.  But you're unnecessarily duplicating code that way.  Using 1 if statement with ors you're able to only write the removal code once.

Answer (score 2):

If the `Document` of the last element is `abc`, it will be removed in the first `if` condition.

`sorted[i]` will the become `undefined` (as you've removed the last element), and when the 2nd `if` runs, you'll get the error you're describing.

You'll be able to fix this by using an `else if`:

```
if (sorted[i].Document=== 'abc') {
    sorted.splice(i, 1);
} else if (sorted[i].Document=== 'xyz') {
    sorted.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Comment: It fails... as i need to remove both the documents... the array contains both.